# Better syntax highlighting for Genie

Tags: genie

I have been using scratch-text-editor on elementaryOS, but it seems to highlight Genie code as if it is C# code.

Is there a way to improve syntax highlighting in that particular OS.

Does any text editor can recognize genie's syntax?

Comment: Scratch uses GtkSourceView for syntax highlighting. In Feb 2015 some basic Genie syntax highlighting was added to GtkSourceView - see this [commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/commit/?id=59fcd0a01b6c9f1f4a82c530671fb97d17ef16f4). So a recent version of Scratch should support Genie. A number of other editors use GtkSourceView for syntax highlighting. This is a development tool question, so I'm not sure why it got closed so quickly - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33036/what-kind-of-questions-about-development-tools-are-appropriate-for-stack-overflo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GEANY is an open-source, lightweight and fast text editor, providing the main features of an IDE, including syntax-highlighting, with support for Genie.

The following article has installation instructions and also mentions that Geany should work fine with elementaryOS.

http://linuxg.net/install-geany-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Genie syntax highlighting has been available in GtkSourceView since [this commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/commit/?id=59fcd0a01b6c9f1f4a82c530671fb97d17ef16f4). So any text editor using GtkSourceView, e.g. gedit, can highlight the Genie syntax. There is room for improvement in the highlighting, e.g. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750945